# Jquery append to table TR

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

I am using the following jQuery code to append to my table:

```
        $("tbody#order_details").append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
        $("tbody#order_details").append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

However, when it executes it places the `<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>` on the top of the page instead of below where the current `<tbody id="order_details">` starts.

The table code is this:

```
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="OrdersTable" 
            style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 0px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <td colspan="3">99996</td>
            <th>Email</th>
            <td colspan="5"><asp:Label ID="billing_email" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
        etc etc....
        </tbody>
             <tbody id="order_details"> 
                <!-- Start looping the orders here -->

             </tbody>
        </table>
```

What am I forgetting to put in order for it to add those two lines AFTER the `<tbody id="order_details">`?

Comment: why do you have an opening `tbody` tag with a closing `thead` tag

Comment: I know its not an answer to your question, but after quite some time generating rows to tables in Jquery I found Knockout.js makes these sort of problems 1000x easier. [Check out this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections), maybe it'll help (keeping in mind this is the second tutorial in a series)

Comment: Have you looked at the error console? Is there anything there?

Comment: @mplungjan: I'm pretty sure the `...` is meant to imply "stuff here that I'm not including for brevity" rather than a literal `...`. The problem does seem to be the two `tbody` tags, the first of which should be `thead`. Most browsers will self-correct the invalid markup, so the OP effectively has two `tbody` tags, and so the rows will be appended to each one.

Comment: I corrected the table layout in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change this html to this:

```
      <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="OrdersTable" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 0px;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Account Number</th>
            <th colspan="3">99996</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th colspan="5"><asp:Label ID="billing_email" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></th>
        </tr>
        etc etc....
        </thead>
        <tbody id="order_details"> 
          <!-- Start looping the orders here -->

        </tbody>
        </table>
```

I think it was because of HTML markups,
I hope this would help.

Comment: `<td>`'s still within the `<thead>`. He also can't append just a `<tr> with no <td>` to his `<tbody>`.

Comment: There is also an unclosed <tr> tag in the head, colspan attributes on the th elements and what looks like data in the head. I think there are larger problems than just a little markup mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write "... " inside a TD.  Should be  ...  .

And for better performance use just #order_details rather than tbody#order_details. As ID is unique jQuery will always find the right element without the need of specifying the tag name

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is not valid and therefore jQuery isn't able to make sense out of what to do.

I have created a jsFiddle with what I think you want: http://jsfiddle.net/DSLBT/

Answer (score 1):

Try this ::

```
$("tbody#order_details").append('<tr><td>...</td></tr><tr><td>...</td></tr>');
```

Comment: That causes it to be at the bottom of the table.